# Android Splash Screen Nine-Patch Not Using Correct Resolution

Tags: android, android-layout, splash-screen, nine-patch

I created a nine-patch splash screen using this tool:

http://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/nine-patches.html

and I placed each "splash.9.png" in the appropriate res/drawable folder (drawable-mdpi, drawable-hdpi, drawable-xxhdpi). Here is my style.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         android:background="#ffff">
    <ImageView android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent" android:scaleType="fitXY" android:src="@drawable/splash" />
</FrameLayout>
```

However, on all devices the mdpi splash screen is being used, which when scaled up looks really blurry. Any advice?

Comment: Are you sure you selected the correct Source density?

Comment: @DeadpoolDude I doubled check and it looks like I uploaded a 1280x720 image but selected xxxhdpi instead of xhdpi. It looks better now, but it looks like the nine patch is not working properly - the entire image is being scaled which is distorting our logo.

Comment: It still looks like it is using the wrong splash screen size. The device has a resolution of 1280x800 and the xhdpi size for the nine-patch is 1282x782. It looks like it is using the mdpi size